# 128-bit integer multiplication

Tags: c, performance, memory

I was given a task at university to calculate the product of 2 128-bit integer numbers in C language and return the older 64 bits. Feel free to use the code below to print out the lower 128 bits of 128-bit integer product.

UPDATED!!!

My teacher suddenly said he'd meant to print the older 64 bits. I decided to use `char *` to store all the 128 bits and print out the multiplication result as 128 lower bits. The code below works:

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>

        char *moveBit(char *s){ // moves the binary string one bit to the left (like s<<1 operation)
            char bit='0';
            char temp='0';
            for(int i=127;i>=0;i--){
                temp = s[i];
                s[i]=bit;
                bit=temp;
            }
            return s;
        }

        char *bitSum(char *a, char *b){ // figures out the sum of two numbers bit by bit

            char rem = '0';
            char* sum = (char *) malloc(129);

            for(int i=127;i>=0;i--){

                int s = (a[i]=='1') + (b[i]=='1') + (rem=='1');

                if (s==3){
                    sum[i]='1';
                    rem='1';
                }else if(s==2){
                    sum[i]='0';
                    rem='1';
                }else{
                    sum[i] = s? '1':'0';
                    rem='0';
                }
            }

            return sum; 
        }

        char *mult(char *a, char *b){

            char* product = (char *) malloc(129);

            for(int i=127;i>=0;i--){

                if(b[i]=='1')
                    product = bitSum(product,a);
                a=moveBit(a);

            }
            return product; 
        }

        int main(){

            char *a = (char *) malloc(129);
            char *b = (char *) malloc(129);

            a="01111111111111111111111111111111101010001101100110100000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110111111001111111111";
            b="01111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110111111001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111011111100111111111";

            printf("%s", mult(a,b));
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure they mean the lowest 64 bits by "last"? That would make it a trivial problem (just multiply the low parts as `uint64_t`). I would consider that the "first" part most of the time.

Comment: In real world case you would use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library. However this is homework, so you need to do it yourself - cheating gets you expelled.

Comment: This might or might not work, try creating an array of 128 bytes (two long longs), store the sum in the first index and if there is overflow the extra bits should go over into the second index. But this might not work since the registers in most computers only store a max of 64 bits but the compiler might handle this somehow, worth a test.

Comment: @Yashwanth That is NOT how it works. Multiplication operations don't simply overflow into random memory that happen to be nearby. It they did that would be bad.

Comment: Yeah I was just throwing ideas around thinking it might overflow if it was an array, but yeah it sounds stupid and have plenty of issues. But would it work if you malloc 128 bytes and try the same thing?

Comment: If you are dumping all but the l.s. then you need to use unsigned.

Comment: If you are defining a mask, your code will be more readable with `long long int cutter = 0x7fffffffffffffffLL`

Comment: @Yashwanth You can't actually multiply numbers directly in memory, on most machines. What will happen is that the CPU will (1) load the numbers into registers (2) do the multiplication and (3) store the result back into memory.

Comment: @jforberg Yeah that was my initial misgiving with my way, see initial comment, thanks for clarifying

Comment: Maybe you're supposed to break up each of the 64-bit multiplicands into two 32-bit pieces (after discarding the high 64-bits of the 128-bit inputs, which seem like an irrelevance), and then do the long multiplication "by hand".  That is, compute four 32-by-32 to 64-bit products, and figure out how to reassemble them into the result you need.  (Hint: one of those products can just be thrown away.)

Comment: `product` in `char *mult()` is not null character terminated.

Answer (score 4):

**long long** is not a 128-bit type on any computer I've worked with. See below for references. I'm also assuming that by "last bits" you mean "high bits". This code will work to get unsigned 128-bit arithmetic going on GCC (adjust the type names for your compiler):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
        __uint128_t x = 9223372036146775308;
        __uint128_t y = 9223372036854709503;
        __uint128_t prod = x * y;
        uint64_t high = prod >> 64;

        printf("%lu\n", high);
}
```

How long are the types on my machine?

Windows: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94z15h2c.aspx

Linux, Mac OSX, "all other systems":
page 13, http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf

Comment: `long` is not a 64 bit type, though it might be. It is guaranteed to be a minimum of 32 bits, which it is on my MSVC compiler. Your MS link says 4 bytes.

Comment: Also, type widths are not dependent upon the compiler, this is a myth. Type widths are defined in the system ABI. Otherwise libraries and programs comiled with different tools would not be able to interoperate.

Comment: Code could use the more portable portable `printf("%" PRIu64, high);` or `printf("%llu\n", (unsigned long long) high);`  OTOH, this solution does depend on`__uint128_t` existing.